# Add empty selection in laravel select with loop options

Tags: php, laravel, html-select

I want to add empty option inside the select field with loop data. Here's the code I'm using

```
<div class="form-group {{$errors->has('duration_id')}}">
    {!! Form::label('duration_id', 'Duration Id', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
    {!! Form::select('duration_id', $durations, null, ('required' == 'required') ? ['class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required'] : ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    {{$errors->first('duration_id')}}
</div>
```

How can I add something like "--select duration--" as the first selection?

[image]

Comment: How are you defining `$durations`? You can prepend a default option with `id` of `null` and `label` of `-- Select Duration --`, etc. Also, `('required' == 'required')` will always be true; should that be something else?

Comment: thank you @TimLewis. is there no other way like what we do in conventional HTML <select> tag?

Comment: You always have the option to not use `Form::select()` :) I'm not sure the syntax of it tbh; I prefer using native HTML for that, like `<select><option>...` But definitely check the answer below; there is of course syntax for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a placeholder to your form select element

```
Form::select('duration_id', $durations, null, ['placeholder' => '--select duration--'], ('required' == 'required') ? ['class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required'] : ['class' => 'form-control'])
```

From the [docs](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.0/html#drop-down-lists)

#### Generating a Drop-Down List With an Empty Placeholder

This will create an `<option>` element with no value as the very first option of your drop-down.

```php
echo Form::select('size', ['L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'], null, ['placeholder' => 'Pick a size...']);
```

Comment: Glag I could help, please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: Thank you @CaddyDZ!